# Bad wheel wobble on Chevy Impala

Tags: wheels

I have a 2009 chevy impala LT 3.5 with a bad wheel wobble on the front passenger side. I've replaced the wheel bearing, had the wheel balanced, had a wheel alignment done, and replaced the control arm. The tie rods were done some time ago. I've fitted two new front tires. Despite all this it still wobbles, and I'm not sure what the cause is or how to fix it. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: How long ago for these items? especially the wheel bearing?

Comment: Was there any damage on the front passenger side, like hitting a curb in the past ?

Comment: Did you check your brake discs?

Comment: Is the rim bent?